# Higlight speech utterance in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I don't succeed to highlight text utterance in SwiftUI. I've found examples of it only in UIKit.
In UIKit it is supposed to be `var label: UILabel!`, but in SwiftUI label has to be String. I've tried to convert `NSMutableAttributedString` into `String` format, inside function, but it's complaining.
How to work it out with `String` formats, so that it works in SwiftUI, too?

```
import AVFoundation

class Speaker: NSObject {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var label: String // <- problem
    

    override init() {
        super.init()
        synth.delegate = self
    }

    func speak(_ string: String) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
        utterance.rate = 0.4
        synth.speak(utterance)
    }
    
    // Functions to highlight text
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
        mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: characterRange)
        label.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you wrap `UILabel` in `UIViewRepresentable` so that you can keep using an attributed string like before:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var speaker = Speaker()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LabelRepresented(text: speaker.label)
        }.onAppear {
            speaker.speak("Hi. This is a test.")
        }
    }
}

struct LabelRepresented: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text : NSAttributedString?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        return UILabel()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = text
    }
}

class Speaker: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    @Published var label: NSAttributedString? // <- change to AttributedString
    

    override init() {
        super.init()
        synth.delegate = self
    }

    func speak(_ string: String) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
        utterance.rate = 0.4
        synth.speak(utterance)
    }
    
    // Functions to highlight text
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
        mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: characterRange)
        label = mutableAttributedString
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        label = NSAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
    }
}
```

I changed `label` into an `NSAttributedString?` and made it a @Published property on an `ObservableObject` -- that way, when it changes, the view gets notified right away.

The `UIViewRepresentable` creates a label and updates it with the attributed string any time it changes.

In the event that you *did* want to try a more pure SwiftUI approach, this blog posts has some good resources for using NSAttributedString in SwiftUI (including the approach I took): https://swiftui-lab.com/attributed-strings-with-swiftui/

Comment: Thanks!!! How can I align the UILablel view? With long text it spreads horizontally out of screen bounds. I've tried `.padding()` in body View, but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes -- this answer details a system for doing just that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469001/how-can-i-get-text-to-wrap-in-a-uilabel-via-uiviewrepresentable-without-having